# Request to improve code to download sequence of URLs

Tags: r, rcurl

in a file I have a table of 23,772 URLs that I need to download. In the code below, that is represented by `dwsites`. Due to the server restrictions, I am only able to download a block of 300 sites at a time. I have accomplished that task with the code below (it is an excerpt of the actual code), but I want to know a better way.

Can you offer any suggestions?

Thank you.

```
dwsites <- data.frame(sites = c(1:23772), url = rep("url", 23772))

dwsitessub <- dwsites[1:300,] # this is the part that I would like to change
curl = getCurlHandle()
pagesnew = list()
for(u in strpatnew) {pagesnew[[u]] = getURLContent(u, curl = curl)}
lapply(seq_along(strpatternew), function(u) cat(pagesnew[[u]], file = file.path("filepath", paste0(strpatternew[[u]], sep = ""))))

dwsitessub <- dwsites[301:459,]
curl = getCurlHandle()
pagesnew = list()
for(u in strpatnew) {pagesnew[[u]] = getURLContent(u, curl = curl)}
lapply(seq_along(strpatternew), function(u) cat(pagesnew[[u]], file = file.path("filepath", paste0(strpatternew[[u]], sep = ""))))

...

dwsitessub <- 23501:nrow(dwsites)
curl = getCurlHandle()
pagesnew = list()
for(u in strpatnew) {pagesnew[[u]] = getURLContent(u, curl = curl)}
lapply(seq_along(strpatternew), function(u) cat(pagesnew[[u]], file = file.path("filepath", paste0(strpatternew[[u]], sep = ""))))
```

Comment: Did you try something like `getURIAsynchronous(uris, maxconnects=200)`. This should download the files asynchronously and till limit the number of connections. This means you will only have call `getURIAsynchronous` once with all the URLs.

Comment: Or it really looks like you want to set the [CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_setopt.html#CURLMOPTMAXTOTALCONNECTIONS) option but i'm not sure RCurl has an interface for that.

Comment: Actually, that option appeared in version 7.30.0 and RCurl seems to be using 7.19.7. So perhaps that was a poor suggestion. Sorry.